# Как обновить linux с live cd?

Tags: linux, live-usb

У меня стоит `Kali Linux`. Мне нужно обновить его, так как на нём почему-то не работает интернет. На live cd всё работает. Live cd тоже `Kali Linux`. Как обновить систему, установленную на жёстком диске с live cd?

Comment: Сделать chroot из live cd в систему

Comment: @andreymal можно немного подробнее?